# Generated columns in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm studying YB for a while and I faced a problem. I try to create [Generated Columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) but this feature is available in PostgreSQL 12 so I would like to know if YB has a plan to support this feature or if there is any solution that is similar to the feature.

This is a example statement.

```sql
CREATE TABLE animal (
id int NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
name text,
normalized_name text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (upper(name::text)) STORED
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment (we will move to PostgreSQL 13 compatibility soon) the `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` is supported but the one on `(upper(name::text))` is not. Workarounds are:

- a trigger to set the column value
- a view to show the upper name on the query
  Note that you don't need to store it in the table to get it indexed with:

```sql
create index animal_normalized_name on animal(upper(name::text));
```